# Is there a way to find anomalies in fuzzy time series?

Tags: stochastic-processes, time-series, fuzzy-set

To clarify, **A fuzzy number**  $p$ is called L-R fuzzy number if its membership function  $\mu_{p}$  can be expressed through    **reference functions**   $L$ and $R$ in the form

$$
\mu_{p} (x) =  
\begin{cases}
\mu_1(x)=L((\overline x - x)/\alpha) & \text{ for } x<\overline x,\\
\mu_2(x)=R((x - \overline x)/\beta) & \text{ for } x\geq \overline x.
\end{cases}
$$

A **fuzzy time series** $(p_t)_t = (<x_t, \alpha_t, \beta_t>)_t$ is a time-indexed sequence of $L-R$ fuzzy numbers.

My question is **is there a way to detect anomalies for this type of time series?**. I understand anomalies as in the context of time series, that is, values that are unexpectedly out of range or that deffer greatly from the expected values of the series.